# Changing text in textblock to italicized on MouseEnter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, system.drawing

I have a textblock that contains some non-italicized text. When the mouse enters the textblock, the text changes through the use of the code behind.  I would like the code behind to also have the ability to change the text to italicized.  This is what I have so far:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="block1"
   Background="Cyan"
   Foreground="{StaticResource myBrush2}"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Height="30"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter"
   MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave"
   Padding="0,7,0,0"
   Text ="Hover Me!"
   TextAlignment="Center"
   Width="100"/>
```

Code Behind (C#):

```
public void TextBlock_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    string blockName = ((TextBlock)sender).Name;
    var block = sender as TextBlock;
    if (block != null && blockName == "block1")
    {
        block.Text = "Yo! I'm TextBlock1";
    }
}
```

I have looked into using System.Drawing and the use of FontStyle.Italic; although I was unsuccessful of actually making it work.

Comment: You really should use styles and triggers for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `XAML` was made for

```
<TextBlock x:Name="block1"
   Background="Cyan"
   Foreground="{StaticResource myBrush2}"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Height="30"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter"
   MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave"
   Padding="0,7,0,0"
   Text ="Hover Me!"
   TextAlignment="Center"
   Width="100">
            <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
```

But, if you really want to, here's an example of how you might implement that functionality from code-behind.

```
private void block1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     SetFontStyle(FontStyles.Italic);
}

private void block1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     SetFontStyle(FontStyles.Normal);
}
private void SetFontStyle(FontStyle style)
{
     block1.FontStyle = style;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know its bad practice to be using the code behind for this scenario.  I am curious though to know if there is a way to implement this without using styles and triggers (strictly code behind).

Comment: Thanks mate! Works perfectly!

Comment: Anytime. You might want to hit the "check" symbol under the answer rating to verify that this question has been resolved. Happy coding!

Comment: No need for a `DataTrigger` here, a `Trigger` on `IsMouseOver` should work.

Comment: Thank you. I have `MVVM` on the brain. My answer has been updated.

Comment: Just expanding a little further: is it possible to italicize only one word with the code-behind shown above?  I am finding that strings cannot be italicized, is this correct?

Comment: The functionality you speak of can be implemented by nesting multiple `TextBlock` components within a `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation.

Comment: You would then apply the `FontStyle` to only the `TextBlock` component(s) that need it.

Comment: Thanks again Jace!